# How can I defined array in array in typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, arraylist

How can I defined array in array  in typescript?

I wanna defined array and I need get data such as that :-

```
  for(let i = 0 ; i< 5 ; i++) {
     List: any = [{
      name: 'data'
      array[i]:data[i] <----- my problem I wanna push data 
      phone: 2132139812
    }]
}
```

Comment: Explain in words what do you exactly need. As of now it is unclear.

Comment: Please review the guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what constitutes a [mcve].

Comment: I wanna push data in array[ i ]

Comment: @Omar still not clear.. who is `List` ? When you say ` array[i]:data[i]` do mean `array` should be an array with a single element ? Could you give example input/output ? To push you just call `push` on an array

Comment: array[i].push(data) in Object

Comment: yes .......................

Comment: I wanna store multi data in array[i]